# Batch File - Set

Tags: batch-file

I want to get  `dir=%dir:~-`here`%`  a var.

I find out that this `dir=%dir:~-%var%%` unfortunaly this doesn`t work.
then I tried :

```
set var=2

echo dir=%%dir:~-%var%%% > file.txt

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do set dir=%%a
```

but then is dir for real `%dir:~-2%`. If anybody understands my, am I asking you is there a way to do it??
THNX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to expand variables in a line *two times*, you need to use Delayed Expansion:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=2
echo dir=!dir:~-%var%! > file.txt
```

The first expansion happen at `%var%`, the second (*delayed*) expansion happen at `!dir:~-2!`.

**EDIT**: Another possible way is use the `call` command that causes that the line be *parsed again*:

```
set var=2
call echo dir=%%dir:~-%var%%% > file.txt
```

When the line is parsed the first time, the first expansion is performed:

```
call echo dir=%dir:~-2% > file.txt
```

The `call` command causes that the line be parsed again and get the final result.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "var=-2"

    echo !cd:~%var%!
```

To use a variable inside a variable substring operation, the easiest way is to use delayed expansion

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it with your example.

Using `call` this way causes an issue with `^` characters and is relatively slower than delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
set dir=aaabbbccc
set var=3
>file.txt call echo dir=%%dir:~-%var%%% 
pause
```